# Turbodbc returns ODBC error state 60 when run from apache2/mod_wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, odbc, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a Django website that uses TURBODBC to execute some direct SQL calls on a legacy database. This works perfectly when using the built in django test server, but when I run it with Apache2 I get the error message: “ODBC error state: 60”.  I feel like it has something to do with running it with mod_wsgi but I am not sure. I have had NO luck with Google. Not even sure what “state: 60” means.

```
Internal Server Error: /inventory/in/
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718077 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718147 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/turbodbc/exceptions.py", line 50, in wrapper
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718213 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]     return f(*args, **kwds)
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718282 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/turbodbc/connect.py", line 44, in connect
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718347 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]      turbodbc_options))
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718410 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056]  turbodbc_intern.Error: ODBC error
[Mon Apr 09 22:01:09.718493 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10074:tid 140709839501056] ] state: 60
```

Questions:
What does "state 60" mean?
What is causing this error?
How do I correct the issue?

simple program to reproduce the error.

```
from turbodbc import connect


def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'
    connect_to_db()
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]


def connect_to_db():
    connection = connect(dsn="odbc-dev", uid='foo', pwd='bar')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

apache2 config:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srcPython3/wsgi_test/hello_world.py

WSGIPythonPath /srcPython3/wsgi_test/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory  /srcPython3/wsgi_test>
        <Files hello_world.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

error.log

```
mod_wsgi (pid=11944): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srcPython3/wsgi_test/hello_world.py'.
[wsgi:error]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/turbodbc/exceptions.py", line 50, in wrapper
[wsgi:error]     return f(*args, **kwds)
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/turbodbc/connect.py", line 44, in connect
[wsgi:error]     turbodbc_options))
[wsgi:error] turbodbc_intern.Error: ODBC error
[wsgi:error] state: 60
[wsgi:error]
[wsgi:error] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[wsgi:error]
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]  File "/srcPython3/wsgi_test/hello_world.py", line 7, in application
[wsgi:error]     connect_to_db()
[wsgi:error]   File "/srcPython3/wsgi_test/hello_world.py", line 15, in connect_to_db
[wsgi:error]     connection = connect(dsn="odbc-dev", uid='foo', pwd='bar')
[wsgi:error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/turbodbc/exceptions.py", line 52, in wrapper
[wsgi:error]     raise DatabaseError(str(e))
[wsgi:error] turbodbc.exceptions.DatabaseError: ODBC error
[wsgi:error] state: 60
```

thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you should open an issue at https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues that can arise with database access under mod_wsgi is that your code runs as the Apache user and not you. Also, environment variables are not inherited from your user login profile.

So if the access mechanism results in using the username of the UNIX account code is running as it will not work. And will not work if you are setting environment variables in your personal account and your code was expecting to see those.

For the first problem, ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode, and then configure daemon mode to run your code as you, and not the Apache user.

For the second, set the environment variables in your WSGI script file before importing any other code.

Comment: you assessment is spot on. Please check out the conversation that I had on the [turbodbc github page](https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc/issues/160).

I solved this by adding
'export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini'
to end of /etc/apache2/envvars